# input button и обработка

Tags: html

Имеется небольшой фильтр:

```
            <div class="filter-item-top">
                <div class="filter-item-left">
                    <input type="button" value="Купить">
                    <input type="button" value="Продать">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-item-right">
                    <input type="button" value="Дом">
                    <input type="button" value="Машину">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
```

Как сделать так, что бы после нажатия определенного значение сохранялось, для дальнейшей обработки PHP скриптом?

Comment: Используя javascript

Answer (score 1):

Например засабмитить форму с инпутом либо послать аяксом значения php скрипту.

Answer (score 0):

Обертку для всего делаете `<form method="post" action="file.php">{you_code}</form>`
добавляете `<input type="submit"/>` и теперь в файле `file.php` данные с формы будут доступны в массиве `$_POST`, с которым дальше можно работать

Comment: Ну и ещё, как минимум, пара способов имеется кроме этого.. Вы бы лучше задачу свою описали что надо сделать конкретно.. Тогда уже стало понятно бы что вам и как делать